# Going on leave during notice period

Tags: resignation, leave

In my contract, I can quit the company given that I give them a 30 days notice.

Also in my contract, I am entitled for 25 business days local leave per year.

During this year, I have not taken any local leave yet. And I am also planning to quit the company on a good term.

I was afraid those 25 days leave will be lost if I quit the company. So a month ago, I requested for all the 25 days leaves straight. It took a bit of convincing but they finally agreed in the end. I also told them at the same time that I am planning to quit the company but ensured them that I will give the 30 days notice as per the contract.

Given some contraints on my side, I have to give them the 30 days notice on the day I will start the 25 days leave.

From my understanding, the reason why we give a notice period is to allow the company enough time to find and handover my current tasks to the person that will replace me. However, since I will be on leave, I won't be there to mentor or help whoever is going to replace.

They are not aware yet of my plan and I am afraid they will take it in a bad way. Also I really want to keep a good relationship with this company.

How will they handle this news?

Will they disallow me to be on leave even if they already agreed earlier?

If so, do they have the right to do so?

What's my best strategy to get the leaves, and quit in a good terms?

Company is in Mauritius.  But I am an expatriate. Quiting this company means leaving the country.

Comment: What is your location? In some jurisdictions paid leave that has been accrued must be paid out if you are resigning or otherwise leaving a job.

Comment: But giving your 30 days notice (which typically includes weekends - so about 4 weeks) when you start 25 days leave (which typically covers work days only, so about 5 weeks) will upset them very much.

Comment: Either your contract or your employee handbook probably covers this situation. Look for sections regarding Separation from the Company and Leave.

Comment: I agree with HorusKol. The location is a crucial element to this question. No one can answer this question until the jurisdiction is known.

Comment: You should keep it mind you might not be entitled to all 25 days considering it's only June 8th, check your contract, on how those days are distributed throughout the year.  You will probably find you are entitled to 12-13 of days, since it's just around 50% of a 26 2-week pay cycle.

Comment: Why not give your notice after the holiday? Or discuss with the employer what they'd prefer? Part of the idea of notice is to allow the employer time to announce your departure, transfer your responsibilities to your existing colleagues in an orderly way, and finalise any short-term tasks. It might not require full attendance over 30 days, but it probably requires at least a few days actual work as well as some advance warning to those who are going to receive your handover.

Comment: You should verify that your leave won't get paid out.

Comment: I added the country

Comment: I left a UK job recently, and due to Covid, etc, I had accumulated 17 days of paid annual leave. I gave 4 months notice. My employer said I HAD to choose either 1. take all leave owed before my finish date or 2. Don't take some or all of it,  and receive as an extra (taxed) payment in my final month's pay,  the salary rate for the days remaining. I chose the first, and my final day was 31 March, but my last day of attendance was 7 March.

Comment: @Michael, that’s how it works in a civilised country. Everyone’s happy. There are countries where giving 4 months notice means the employer gives you two weeks and you get nothing for your 17 days, and that’s where employees quite rightfully do what they can do get what they should be owed, and it hurts the company deservedly.

Comment: @gnasher729 - I gave 4 months notice so that the pension people could start paying me as soon as I left. I could have given 1 month notice on Feb 28 and walked out on March 7, like one of my old bosses did, and wait for the backdated pension to be calculated and activated. My UK (Civil Service) employer gave a 25 year long service award: either  £150 (taxed), or a gift of that value (such as a 'carriage clock' the guidance says, not to include alcoholic beverages or tobacco) or one week's extra leave. Guess which one most people choose. The John Lewis Partnership gives six months leave.

Answer (score 4):

If you want to quit on good terms, you need to work with your employer to find a solution that works well for them, or at least be willing to be seen to make some accommodations.

There is no way you can take leave for a large remaining chunk of your remaining time and not run the risk of causing problems.

Just because your leave has been approved doesn't mean you can't cancel it yourself.

You need to figure out what is most important to you, as I don't think you can satisfy everything here.

Answer (score 2):

> What's my best strategy to get the leaves, and quit in a good terms?

You already have the leave.

As for quitting on good terms, this is unrealistic so just do whatever you need to do. Don't expect people to be happy about it.

Answer (score -3):

> From my understanding, the reason why we give a notice period is to allow the company enough time to find and handover my current tasks to the person that will replace me

**Wrong.** Notice period is to protect the worker, either as a part of social policy hardly fought by labor unions, or as a bonus gracefully given by the company.

The company should be always prepared for a worker to immediately leave (bus factor), otherwise they screw themselves.

If your local leave is an employment bonus, insist of using it, otherwise you'll loose it. Many companies are happy if they can fill the notice period of unhappy worker that leaves with their days off. This way they won't have negative impact on others (for example, discussing why they leave, which often leads to blaming company etc.)